# Android. Google map. How to draw polygon from array

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, wkt

I m new to android app development.
I have WKT (POLYGON)
How to draw polygon on google map from wkt?

I try

```
    String str;

        ArrayList<String> coordinates = new ArrayList<String>();

        str = tvwkt.getText().toString();

        str = str.replaceAll("\\(", "");
        str = str.replaceAll("\\)", "");
        str = str.replaceAll("POLYGON", "");
        str = str.replaceAll("POINT", "");
        str = str.replaceAll(", ", ",");
        str = str.replaceAll(" ", ",");
        str = str.replaceAll(",,", ",");


        String[] commatokens = str.split(",");
            for (String commatoken : commatokens) {
                coordinates.add(commatoken);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {

            String[] tokens = coordinates.get(i).split("\\s");
            for (String token : tokens) {

                listPoints.add(token);
            }

        }

        PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions().addAll(listPoints).strokeColor(Color.BLUE).fillColor(Color.CYAN).strokeWidth(7);

        polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
```

But its not work.
Hepl me please. 
thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the output you got, or more specifically what did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it.

Read LatLong from WKT and add to Array

```
private LatLng[] GetPolygonPoints(String polygonWkt) {

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    wkt = bundle.getString("wkt");
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d*\\.\\d+)\\s(\\d*\\.\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(wkt);
    String point;

    while (m.find()){
        point =  wkt.substring(m.start(), m.end());
        points.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)), Double.parseDouble(m.group(2))));
    }
    return points.toArray(new LatLng[points.size()]);

}
```

then draw polygon

```
    public void Draw_Polygon() {

    LatLng[] points = GetPolygonPoints(polygonWkt);

        Polygon p = mMap.addPolygon(
                new PolygonOptions()
                        .add(points)
                        .strokeWidth(7)
                        .fillColor(Color.CYAN)
                        .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
        );

    //Calculate the markers to get their position
    LatLngBounds.Builder b = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (LatLng point : points) {
        b.include(point);
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = b.build();
    //Change the padding as per needed
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20,20,5);
    mMap.animateCamera(cu);

}
```

finally

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    LatLng[] points = GetPolygonPoints(polygonWkt);

    if (points.length >3){

        Draw_Polygon();

    }
    else {

        Add_Markers();

    }

}
```

Comment: This code is incorrect, latitude and longitude are set backwards and negative values are not taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better aproach, for this sample WKT Polygon:

```
    wkt = "POLYGON((-84.22800686845923 40.137783757219864,-82.71787050257508 33.66027041269767,-78.6190283330219 37.694486391034445,-84.22800686845923 40.137783757219864))";
```

We need to get the negative values, and also order correctly the lat/long

```
private LatLng[] getPolygonPoints() {
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d*\\.\\d+)\\s(\\d*\\.\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(wkt);
    String point;

    while (m.find()) {
        point = wkt.substring(m.start() - 1, m.end());
        points.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(point.split(" ")[1]), Double.parseDouble(point.split(" ")[0])));
    }
    return points.toArray(new LatLng[points.size()]);
}
```

And then draw the polygon like the last response:

```
public void drawPolygon() {
    LatLng[] points = getPolygonPoints();
    Polygon p = mMap.addPolygon(
            new PolygonOptions()
                    .add(points)
                    .strokeWidth(7)
                    .fillColor(Color.CYAN)
                    .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
    );

    //Calculate the markers to get their position
    LatLngBounds.Builder b = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (LatLng point : points) {
        b.include(point);
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = b.build();
    //Change the padding as per needed
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20, 20, 5);
    mMap.animateCamera(cu);

}
```